# how to save all the deleted file names in a .txt file using svn ant Ant

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, git-svn

i'm working in SVN commands using Ant, and i face a problem that i can't list all the deleted files from the repository .... here is the code to show all the changes that have been done in the project ....

```
<target name ="change">
    <svn username="username" password="password">
    <log path="D:\url\to\the\file" destFile="changes.txt" asXml="false"/>
    </svn>
</target>
```

it using this file, but i want to know how i can insert an argument

i manage to get that data using the command prompt here is the command

svn log -v  --xml D:\url\to\the\file | grep 'action="D"'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`<exec>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task to execute `svn log -v --xml D:\url\to\the\file | grep 'action="D"'` and get what you need. Or you have to extend / modify the `svn` task yourself.